# Is Series.isin() inconsistent for 'str' and 'int' type values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series('1')
b = pd.Series(1)
a.isin(b)
```

0    False

dtype: bool

```
b.isin(a)
```

0    True

dtype: bool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a similar open issue for `.isin()` called **Pandas doesn't always cast strings to int consistently when using .isin()**: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24918

The issue was opened and last commented on in January 2019.